# foreach loop in android for breaking data

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

this is my SQLBlog class and getDataFunc is the function  where i am getting result from database

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLBlog {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name"; 
    public static final String KEY_BLOG = "persons_blog";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "blog";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "admin_blog";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBhelper ourhelper;
    private final Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase;

    private static class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBhelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("Create table "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" (" + KEY_ROWID + " Integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                        KEY_NAME +" text not null, "+
                        KEY_BLOG +" text not null);");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+ DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        }
    public SQLBlog(Context c){
        ourcontext=c;
    }

    public SQLBlog open() throws SQLException{
        ourhelper= new DBhelper(ourcontext);
        ourdatabase= ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }
    public void close(){

        ourhelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, String blog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_BLOG, blog);
        return ourdatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getDataFunc() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String columns[]= new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_BLOG};
        Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result= "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iBlog = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BLOG);

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
         result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iBlog) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Here i am using that result to show blogs to my user

```
public class SQLLiteView extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
        TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
        SQLBlog getdata = new SQLBlog(this);
        getdata.open();
        String data = getdata.getDataFunc();
        getdata.close();
        tv.setText(data);
    }



}
```

But the problem is i am getting data as a string but i want to show the data more dynamically like...

hey guys how are you              :Posted By Jack

//comments will be given here...

How to get data from my database and put it on a ListView that is clickable  :Posted By Nicole

//comment goes here

How can i achieve this..need help...i think i am searching for some type foreach loop like php...which can break the data..but as i am using String as return type i cant get it..

Comment: Please give your database structure about comments and posts, i think it will help. But little advice : You should create a class who represent your tables and use the custom adapter of listviews to map the data (more info about adapters & listview : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: i post the whole class ..check it out..@NeeL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `foreach`loop:

```
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
         result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iBlog) + "\n";
    }
```

Here you concate your string together, just put this `foreach` loop in your activity (return the `cursor`, instead of `String`) or make a list with a new class which has three fields and store your fields.

Here an example of wrapping your results in a class - which generally is a good idea anyway. But I really recommend to read some stuff about java and objectoriented programming.

If you don't want to reutrn the cursor to the activity you could to something like this.
First createa new class which keeps blog-objects:

```
public class Blog {

    private String author;
    private String content;

    public Blog(String author, String content){
        this.author = author;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return content;
    }
}
```

And then change your db-method like this:

```
public List<Blog> getDataFunc() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String columns[]= new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_BLOG};
    Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<Blog> results = new ArrayList<Blog>();
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iBlog = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BLOG);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
     results.add(new Blog(c.getString(iName),c.getString(iBlog)));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Now in your activity you can iterate like this:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
    SQLBlog getdata = new SQLBlog(this);
    getdata.open();
    for(Blog blog : getdata.getDataFunc()){
        Log.v("tag",blog.getAuthor());
        Log.v("tag",blog.getContent());
    }
    getdata.close();
    tv.setText(data);
}
```

Comment: what does this line mean??... Log.v("tag",blog.getAuthor());

Comment: can you suggest me where to read about java and objectoriented programming..it should be helpful

Comment: You really should learn OOP & java+android base before trying to do things like that @KingshukDeb =) You can start by typing OOP in java on google i'm sure you will find a lot of helpful links

Answer (score 1):

First , create a class which will store your content :

```
public class BlogEntry { //I suppose you will call that a BlogEntry ?
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String question;
    public String blog;
    public ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
}
```

And the class to store your comments :

```
public class Comment {
    public int id;
    public int questionId;
    public String name;
    public String comment;
    public String blog;

}
```

Then create 2 tables with your SQLBlog class which will match the data described in those two classes.

You should now create a method like :

```
public ArrayList<BlogEntry> getAllEntries() {

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM blogentries", null);
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iBlog = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BLOG);
    int iQuestion = c.getColumnIndex("question");

    //table comment
    int row = c.getColumnIndex("id");
    int name = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int blog = c.getColumnIndex("blog");
    int iComment = c.getColumnIndex("comment");

    ArrayList<BlogEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BlogEntry>();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        BlogEntry b = new BlogEntry();
        b.id = c.getInt(iRow);
        b.name = c.getString(iName);
        b.blog = c.getString(iBlog);
        b.question = c.getString(iQuestion);
        Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE questionId=? ORDER BY id ASC", new String[]{String.valueOf(b.id)});

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            Comment com = new Comment();
            com.questionId = b.id;
            com.id = c.getInt(row);
            com.name = c.getString(name);
            com.blog = c.getString(blog);
            com.comment = c.getString(iComment);
            b.comments.add(com);
        }
        entries.add(b);
    }
    return entries;
}
```

You should have something you can work with now, next step is to create an activity with a listview and an adapter to map the datas.

In my example i will use a ExpandableListView who looks like : [image: ExpandableListView]

Here is the ListViewLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:baselineAligned="false">
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/myExpandableListView "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your activity :

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.myExpandableListView);
    ArrayList<BlogEntry> entries = new SQLBlog().getAllEntries();
    list.setAdapter(new MyExpandableListAdapter(entries));
}
```

We need to create an item layout : (call it itemlayout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:baselineAligned="false">
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextViewThatWillHoldTheQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your MyExpandableListAdapter :

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    ArrayList<BlogEntry> entries;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(ArrayList<BlogEntry> entries, Context ctx) {
        this.entries = entries;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return entries.get(groupPosition).comments.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return entries.get(groupPosition).comments.get(childPosition).id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        commentHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.id.itemlayout, null); //we use the same for comment and blogentry but you shouldn't coz you want the display to change
            holder.myTextViewThatHoldComment = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTextViewThatWillHoldTheQuestion);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (commentHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Comment item = (Comment)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        holder.myTextViewThatHoldComment.setText(item.comment);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return entries.get(groupPosition).comments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return entries.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return entries.get(groupPosition).id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        BlogEntryHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.id.itemlayout, null); //we use the same for comment and blogentry but you shouldn't coz you want the display to change
            holder.myTextViewThatHoldQuestion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTextViewThatWillHoldTheQuestion);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (BlogEntryHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        BlogEntry item = (BlogEntry)getGroup(groupPosition);
        holder.myTextViewThatHoldComment.setText(item.question);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    private  class BlogEntryHolder{
        TextView myTextViewThatHoldQuestion;
    }
    private  class commentHolder{
        TextView myTextViewThatHoldComment;
    }

}
```

You should have something like you asked :)