# Refactoring table insertion methods in a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, refactoring

I hope I'm not asking something that has a direct answer in embedded database programming. If I am, please direct me to the answer and I will close this question.

My question is the following: suppose I have a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` in my android application. This subclass overrides the appropriate methods, and also creates a database (say database.db) and I want it to have some functionality for inserting things into the database (i.e to each table). How can I write these methods so that there is little code duplication? The reason I ask this is because each insertion method does exactly the same thing in general: get the database for writing, create the `ContentValues` object, fill it with the right data, and use the `insert` method in `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

The other option, if I don't want to have an insert method per table, is to just run raw queries from a reference I have to this subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. To be honest, neither seem to be good solutions to the problem of having an easy to use API to insert/delete/query a database via this class. I would love some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. You need to move your SQLiteOpenHelper class in another class file and reuse code of it every time you need to open your db, get query or insert values?

If yes - I can provide links for you to read abroad SO, also some snippets for you.

Lets suggest you have subclass

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public DBHelper(Context context) {...}

   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {...}

   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {...}

}
```

Create new java class in your package named DBHelper and move whole code of DBHelper inside of it. Than, when you need reference of db in your code, use this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   DBHelper dbHelper;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
   SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

   //rest of your code goes here

}
```

If you want to get data from db without typing code for cursor and query each time, you can go and read answer, provided by OschtärEi ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581146/foreach-loop-in-android-for-breaking-data))